# MYSQL SUM Value

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table :

table structure for "kegiatanrenja"

```
idkegiatan  tahun koderekening   detail
renja001    2001  1.03.03.04.1     A
renja002    2001  1.03.03.03.2     B
renja003    2001  1.08.08.05.3     C
renja004    2001  1.08.08.05.2     D
```

table structure for "sumberdana"

```
idkegiatan    nilai   kodesumberdana
renja001      100     1
renja002      200     2
renja003      50      1
renja004      100     1
```

I want to create a query that displays the value of all the columns "nilai" if MID (koderekening, 9,2) the same value, along with the value of another column, where each row in the group by where each row in the group by MID (koderekening, 9,2).

```
kode rekening      nilai_group(SUM Of value the same kode MID(koderekening,9,2) 
1.03.03.04         300                                                         
1.08.08.05         150
```

please help, every  suggestion will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT    LEFT(koderekeneing,0,10), sum (nilal) 
FROM      kegiatanrenja k 
JOIN      sumberdana s ON s.idkegiatan = k.idkegiatan 
GROUP BY  MID(koderekening,9,2)
UNION
SELECT    'ALL', sum (nilal) 
FROM      kegiatanrenja k 
JOIN      sumberdana s ON s.idkegiatan = k.idkegiatan
```

Please note, this is *VERY* easy, so if you are asking this sort of question on stack lot, you are going to receive a negative response.  Please get yourself a good SQL book and do some studying.

Comment: Thank you very much.
what if I want to get  total of all the values ​​together with the above query.